# Quarkus + reactive rabbitMQ | DLQ doesn't set dead letters (DLX, DLK)

Tags: java, rabbitmq, quarkus

I'm using quarkus 2.16.3 and reactive messaging rabbitmq. My consumers and producers works, but I noticed that when I create queues with my application, the DLQ doesn't set DLX and DLK.
This is my configuration in application.properties, I attached an image of rabbitmq management [This is the attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiT5f.png).

```
mp.messaging.incoming.consumerExample.connector=smallrye-rabbitmq
mp.messaging.incoming.consumerExample.exchange.declare=true
mp.messaging.incoming.consumerExample.exchange.name=consumerExample
mp.messaging.incoming.consumerExample.exchange.type=topic
mp.messaging.incoming.consumerExample.queue.name=consumerExample
mp.messaging.incoming.consumerExample.routing-keys=consumerExample
mp.messaging.incoming.consumerExample.auto-bind-dlq=true
mp.messaging.incoming.consumerExample.dead-letter-exchange=DLX
mp.messaging.incoming.consumerExample.dead-letter-routing-key=DLX-reportDLX
mp.messaging.incoming.consumerExample.dlx.declare=true
```

I tried a lot of configurations in the application.properties, but nothing, also online I didn't find nothing useful